# Informal language and moderation

Tags: discussion, edits

"Well, sorry for being me, and communicating in a certain way"

...that's the feeling I've had a few times on Stack Overflow after my posts has been comically pointlessly moderated by other members of the community.

Often posts, (including my own) benefit from having another set (or sets) of eyes taking a look at it, and making it more readable by fixing typos and formatting errors. But when people start removing the little twists of personal flair here and there, I get confused. Is it not allowed having your own writing style?

I have the feeling that this is a case of "Too many cooks spoil the broth". Too many moderators, for too few questions. People who want to moderate get bored, and start fixing where no fixing is required.

What I want to ask here, is who makes the decision on what type of language is allowed, and what isn't? Are short formal sentences always more readable than a flair of spoken language? Is it justified to start removing "Thank you"'s and emoticons, just because they don't provide constructively to the discussion?

I haven't seen any rules on the official guidelines against it.

This isn't a rant about a particular case of moderation, but rather a general question about whether the community has developed their own guidelines where phrases such as "Here's the thing...", "In order to...", and "Can you please help me with..." is no longer allowed when writing a question?

What are your thoughts?

Comment: We do prefer questions to be *concise and to the point*. Fluff like *Can you please help me with..* is extraneous to that goal.

Comment: You don't think there's cases where fluff might actually be benefitial? :)

Comment: ^ Same for fluff like _"Hello, ..." "Thanks, ..."_ etc.

Comment: @Scherling: Nope. Convince us ;-)

Comment: I have seen some beneficial fluff, just not in a SO post. ;)

Comment: @Scherling: You'll have to show me how that would be beneficial.

Comment: That's a pretty wide question you've got here. I agree with Martijn Pieters that things like "Can you please help me with..." should be edited out but I really don't see why "in order to...", or "here's the thing..." should be edited in favor of something else or edited out. This veers into imposing one's *own stylistic choices* on another, a practice that I find reprehensible. (It's one thing to edit to align a post with *SO's editorial standards*, it's another to edit to align a post with one's *own* preferences.)

Comment: Related: [What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131009)

Comment: "Too many moderators, for too few questions" -- WAT

Comment: worth noting: "Thanks!", "Hello dear so-pedians", "Help me please" are different from "here's the thing". The former is "useless fluff" / "polite conversation", and the latter is stylistic choice of presentation...

Comment: @JanDvorak, I have no idea whether that's the case. Possibly not. But it seems perculiar that someone would take time out of their busy schedule to remove a few pointless words which dosen't alter the readability or message

Comment: @gnat, there's not much fun in a discussion thread which is closed ;) Interesting read nontheless

Answer (score 16):

A few things about the fluff removals, the signature deletions and the whole "unfriendliness".

Stackoverflow aims to be a site for "Professionals and Enthusiasts", where you can find knowledge in a centralized place, with **as little distraction as possible.**

Now aiming for a high Signal:Noise ratio makes some things difficult. For example polite conversation.

Let's face it. Most of polite conversation is just beating around the bush:

> A: Hello dear Bob. How are you on this lovely summer day?
> B: Oh hello Alice. I am fine. How are you?
> A: Oh Bob thank you for asking, I am wonderful.
> B: Say Alice, what brings you here today on this wonderful day?
> A: Bob, listen I have a small problem there...

.... Okay... How long did it take to get to the core of the problem now?? That's quite some text if all you wanted to know was: "Do you know why this code, that's supposed to do X doesn't work?"

**This** is the No.1  reason to remove things like "Hello", "Hi, all", [...] as well as things like "Thanks in advance!", "Please help", "Any leads appreciated", [...]

All this stuff is often referred to as "fluff", and subject to removing edits. Anyone who wants to hear this stuff isn't really in the best place. We're <s>not nice.</s> trying to be concise and precise.

There's some other things I probably didn't think of, but if I read your question correctly there's something else:

#### Rhetoric

If someone comes and edits your posts in some rhetoric instances, stuff like "And here's" -> "here's" then that's a useless edit, and by all means, if there's an edit only for stuff like that, by all means, roll it back ;)

Your rhetorics are your writing-signature, and no one should be encouraged to stamp his own signature on your post if you don't want it. But be prepared, fluff is not a writing-signature, it's ... different, and if you rollback fluff-removals... well whatever happens then.

Comment: Thank you. I actually agree with you on this. I'll consider rolling back the pointless edits in the future ;)

Comment: _that's supposed to do X doesn't work?_  What is _doesn't work_?  Any errors?

Answer (score 9):

> Quick question, I just can't seem to find the answer on google

That is not flair, just an excuse up front that you haven't spent enough time on the question.

> Here's the thing, in this particular case...

That's fluff, not flair.

> I'm sure the answer is super obvious, but I just can't seem to figure it out

Not flair either, we already know that you can't figure it out or you wouldn't have asked the question.  No need to apologize.

The editor did a good job of making your post more *concise*, getting to the point quicker without unnecessarily taking the time of the reader to have to scan through the fluff.  By far most readers of your post will *not* have the same motivations as you do, just the same problem that they are trying to solve.  A blog is a decent place to flex your writing muscles, not an SO post.

Comment: Not about this particular case, but an open discussion about the subject of editing text that neither hurts nor helps the message. You do bring an interesting point across, though. Please give me an example of something that's flair, but not fluff.

Comment: I personally keep it very modest in my own posts.  But won't avoid the opportunity to write "This will byte you in the future".  Geeky humor.

Answer (score 7):

The author's voice and intent should be respected by editors, and they generally are. There are some things that many consider to be *always* superfluous - such as greetings, salutations and signatures.

And then we have edits for brevity, which *coincide* with the removal of superfluous text, but require some skill to do correctly while keeping sight of the goal of preserving the original author's voice and intent. You might drift off on tangents; you might include too *much* back story - you've made the question much longer than it essentially *needs* to be in order to get an answer. Questions should be highly optimized for the *answerer's* time, and folks strive for that. Sometimes though, folks cut out a bit *too* much, and it's okay to edit some of it back in provided that you understand what the editor was trying to do.

There's nothing wrong with "Can you please tell me why this isn't working?" and if someone edited that to simply say "Why isn't this working?" I'd probably change it back - it might have been caught up in some other changes that actually improve the post. If that's *all* the person edited, then you're well within your rights to roll it back.

Removing stuff like "please help" "thanks" and other unnecessary bits that are on their own lines, or that proliferate in the post *would* be acceptable though.

Put simply, if you think someone is stepping on your 'voice' as an author, then the first thing to do is try to take a look at what they were trying to change and why. You might find another way of saying it, or you might simply say "this is just a silly edit, it doesn't make my post any better" and roll it back. Just don't get into a rollback war with anyone - flag for a mod if you see that starting to set up.

Comment: +1, have you personally seen people making pointless edits to your posts?

Comment: @Scherling I've changed some where I thought the editor went a little too far (while having good intentions) and a bit too much of the personality I was trying to put into the post was lost. There have also been times where I was _very_ oddly specific intentionally, and an edit changed that, which I corrected. _Most_ edits to my posts have been helpful, and I've never come close to an edit war.

Answer (score 6):

We are all here for a reason. Either you have a problem you want an answer to, or we're here to answer questions regarding your problems. This is fundamentally different from social situations (even in an office context) where we would "bother" people with our questions for example.

If I have a question for one of my busy colleagues, I'd ask them "Sorry to disturb you, but do you have a moment to help me out? I have this problem I'm stuck on, and I can't seem to figure out what's going wrong". Seems fair enough right? The thing is though that such a statement would be completely unnecessary here. If you have a question, we can assume it's a problem you haven't been able to solve. And if I'm here to answer it, then you're certainly not disturbing me.

[Let's pick an example of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26233596/revisions).

There is

> Quick question, I just can't seem to find the answer on Google

That doesn't really matter, does it? Quick or slow is not all that important. And that you couldn't find it when using Google is not information we really need to have. If that is how you would indicate that you've done your research, you're doing it wrong anyway. So that line, while technically not a problem, can simply be removed because it doesn't add anything to the question.

> Here's the thing, in this particular case, the number is a string.

While I might have left that one alone, all that is relevant is "In this particular case ...".

> I'm sure the answer is super obvious, but I just can't seem to figure it out,

Of course you can't figure it out. No need to ask the question if you could. And any assumption about the answering being obvious is unnecessary, and perhaps plain wrong. Again, it doesn't add anything of value to the question.

Are these parts bad? Not really, and certainly not in a one on one social context. But for Stack Overflow it's fluff. Just get to the point. You don't have to apologize for asking a question. And if the question is clear you're not wasting anybody's time, or disturbing anyone while they should have spent their time on something else.

If that is how you naturally write, you're not really causing any harm. But I would also edit it out if I saw it. As long as your post is not harmed (and in this case actually cleaned up a tad) then that's just fine.

Comment: As I said, this isn't about a particular edit, but rather a general discussion about what is allowed. In the above example, all edits are perfectly justified, not arguing that. I'm interested in the reasoning behind "pointless" edits. I'd argue that removing a word that neither hurts nor helps getting the message across is just as pointless as the word itself ;)

Comment: Sure, the specific case was just a handy illustration @Scherling. The thing is though that if content is pointless, or at best doesn't add anything of value to a post, removing it is doing us all a service. Even if minimal. And if we have users who are willing to spend time on it, let them. Your personality doesn't really matter all that much when all we're really looking for it content that is useful to the wider audience of the internet.

Comment: I completely agree that personality dosen't matter. But there's a huge difference between "dosen't matter" and "not allowed". I feel like the latter being the case here

Comment: Not really @Scherling. The difference between "doesn't matter" and "not allowed" would be an edit and a punishment. All that happened is an edit. You're not being punished, nor should you be.

Answer (score 3):

I am Shadow adn I am a programmer want to answer you question. In my spare time I like to play word association games with my friends in my den.

Plz dont fix my answer becaue I have my own style.

*The above reflects my thoughts*

i hope thiz helpz

regardz and have a nize day

Comment: Grrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr

Comment: @Bart oh, so you're here! :D

Comment: No. not helpful, not useful and not really answering the core question. This is not about poor orthography and grammar, but about the fluff.

Comment: Trying a little too hard, imo.

Comment: OK, I just shared my thoughts, as the OP requested. We should not stop editing.

Comment: ... At least you capitalized your 'i's.

Comment: Which is exactly why the post isn't credible, @MichaelT ;-)

Comment: You seem to be proposing that if people are allowed to write in their own style, it entails tossing all standards out the window. Untrue.

Comment: @Louis not really, my point is that if we start banning edits changing some things, it won't end there, and people would be discouraged from editing anything.

Comment: I actively participate in "comically pointlessly moderated by other members of the community." I edited the question and now I am about to edit this answer in 3... 2... 1...

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion boom! Time expired :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard a) If that's what you meant to say, why not just say it? b) The question is not suggesting that edits be banned.

Comment: @Louis "I haven't seen any rules on the official guidelines against it" which means he want such rules. Rules means banning edits which do not follow them. As for saying it, maybe I'll add it, thought it's clear enough. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's a strained interpretation.

Comment: This does not plz me. Not one bit. :P

Comment: @Tim not even one byte? :)

Comment: @TimPost I for one am [totally plzd by outstanding edit made by Peter in rev 3](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/274368/revisions). This alone makes it unique and worth keeping forever. Can't believe I have seen it