# How is "Satan hold your orgasm" offensive remark?

Tags: discussion, offensive

Someone edited my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26377607/why-special-rules-for-for-statement-scope/26379663#26379663), and s/he removed part of the answer that said "Satan hold your orgasm", and the summary of the edit said that it is offensive remark. Why is that? Is it religious stuff? (I thought they hated satan)

Comment: Really? You see nothing wrong with that?

Comment: What exactly was the point of including that in your answer in the first place?

Comment: @bluefeet I thought to rmove it because it's joke. (that doesn't need to be part of the answer) But don't know why it's offensive.

Comment: It's incomprehensible, not offensive.

Comment: Even if it weren't offensive (I can't say either way), it doesn't add anything to the answer—it's noise and should be omitted.

Comment: @KugBuBu IMO it was completely inappropriate to include that even if you thought it was a joke.

Comment: @bluefeet Because of that I thought of removing it while not being sure. So I let it be there.

Comment: @KugBuBu You are missing the point, the problem is that you included it in the first place.  It doesn't matter that you _thought_ about removing it, you included it and now you are questioning why someone else edited it out.

Comment: @bluefeet My question is about the summary edit, I was actually OK about removing that, I didn't rolled back. I thought it was vaguely empathy towards satanism. (If it came down to that, I can make anything offensive)

Comment: @KugBuBu Someone found it offensive and they removed it, enough said.

Comment: @gnat I don't think my question is talking particulary on the edit-summary feature, just what someone wrote for me something there.

Comment: hm. the reality is that it lent nothing of value to your answer. ergo, it was superfluous and distracted from an otherwise reasonable answer. you do yourself a disservice by adding such distractions because you erode your own credibility. the editor did a service for you, even if they did it by saying it was "offensive." is that what's got you upset? that they said, "offensive?"

Comment: you mean, if [edit summary](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26379663/3 "'Remove offensive remark'") was like, "Remove [superfluous](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274366/informal-language-and-moderation) remark", you would still ask this question at meta?

Comment: @gnat I just wanted to know why that person found it offensive. I know it's superflous. You added that tag on purpose :)?

Comment: @KugBuBu why does *anyone* find *anything* offensive. we all operate with a sense of ethics and norms. apparently that person felt that you crossed the line of these constructs.

Comment: I added this tag to indicate for question readers that it is about contents of a specific [meta-tag:edit-summary]

Comment: a case of tilting at windmills

Comment: @gnat The relevance of the questions at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=summary-edit towards this tag not as relevant as this question.

Comment: @swasheck I think I got it. Actually I am starting to feel regret about asking this question.

Comment: it only looks so, because this tag does not yet have a [proper wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/edit-summary/info) (or, more precisely, its wiki was lost in [meta-tag:mso-mse-split])

Comment: I like a little bit of humor here and there. But most people don't. I once made a joke that went like *"some programming languages from the Old Testament (COBOL, Fortran, SmallTalk etc.)"*.  It was on topic - it was about a question about why some languages are 0-indexed and some others not - but some people gave me hell because of the "from Old Testament" part, saying it was noise. And you see, they are right. Some people do legitimately feel distracted if you add a little humor to a post (I think due to a lot of them having Asperger), and as such it is right to remove it from questions.

Comment: @Renan: I think that _"I think due to a lot of them having Asperger"_ could again be interpreted as being offensive. Is this a second-level offensive inception? :p

Comment: @Renan I have mild Asperger and I found it offensive, jk but you are wrong. We can take jokes but I think it's due to the seriousness people put into the site to make it better. Jokes just ruin it. This site is dissocial too, it goes nautral-against it.

Comment: @KugBuBu I am almost convinced that every hardcore programmer in the world - me included - has it. But then again, you kinda answered your own original question with your latest comment.

Comment: @Renan This is halfly quoted from the answers below. I think it's too much for this post. Need to close this question for comments too :(. Let's stop this. (26 comments)

Comment: I find using the term 'orgasm' in this context to be unprofessional and not-suitable-for-work. In can see that if you extend 'offensive' to include NSFW terminology then your remark was offensive. It was off-colour and should not have been used.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That text was noise, and it's entirely acceptable to remove it solely on that basis.  I don't see it as offensive at all, so I would say that the revision text isn't appropriate, even though the removal is.

Comment: But that's what I asked about. Never mind I got that the editor got a mistake.

Comment: @KugBuBu I'm agreeing with you entirely that the text isn't offensive, and shouldn't be removed on those grounds.  I'm also saying that it should be removed for reasons not yet brought up by either of you.  Someone did the right thing for the wrong reasons.

Comment: @Servy While I don't personally think I'd call it "offensive" I know a lot of people who would. So it _is_ offensive to some people. We just don't care. On the flip side, the editor could have instead flipped out and flagged as "offensive" (I would expect it would probably get declined and a mod would just edit) but instead took the calm route for it and just edited.

Comment: @Kendra What about it is offensive?

Comment: @Kendra If you know the reason you can actually answer my question here. How that person found it offensive? EDIT: comment duplicate...

Comment: As I said, I don't personally find it offensive. But I know people that would be offended at the "Satan" mention, and I know people that would be offended at the "orgasam" mention. (The last group isn't the group that I'm speaking for in this case.) The fact that "Satan" isn't used here in a religious sense doesn't mean people won't take it that way. It's really easy to offend people who are very religious.

Comment: @KugBuBu It's just a guess; No one will know without asking the editor directly, because the editor could have found it offensive for a completely different reason.

Comment: @Kendra Since when is *mentioning* Satan offensive?  On what basis is the use of that word offensive?  What is offensive about the use of the word "orgasm"?  Clearly both terms are irrelevant to the post at hand, but had either of those terms (or even the entire phrase) actually been relevant to the post at hand I see no basis for removing it.  That someone, somewhere, at some time, might, possibly, maybe, find something offensive isn't reason to remove that content.  The site would be empty if that were true.

Comment: @Kendra I am agreeing with Servy here. If it's too specific or irrational way of getting offended it can't be accept. For example: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275736, the reason of downvotes aren't to offend, but new users seem find it as if it is. Should we remove downvotes? Too irrational to.

Comment: @Servy As I said, it's really easy to offend people who are very religious. I've managed it before in just that way. And as I said, I'm not really speaking for the second group. As the first group is a large and rational (most of the time) group, I thought it best to point them out.

Comment: @KugBuBu You know, you really could just ping the editor and ask them what they found offensive. Or point them here so they can answer, though if that offends them it'd probably not go well.

Comment: @Kendra How to ping him? I am not interested anymore in the question actually, but more interested in how.

Answer (score 26):

That remark is simply unprofessional. The standard for Stack Overflow isn't just being non-offensive, it is meant to be a place for professional programmers and you should use professional language there.

This is not about censoring bad words or any religious sensibilities. It is good practice to avoid such potentionally problematic remarks if they aren't necessary.

Comment: As I said in the comments `I thought to rmove it because it's joke`, but that doesn't answer the question. I guess s\he didn't knew what it was.

Comment: You can think all you want but in the end you have to actually do it too. It's noise without any value, ergo it's removed. Nothing new under the sun.

Comment: @KugBuBu: Whether something is offensive or not depends on the person who reads it. Obviously your phrase isn't offensive for you, also not for me. But I agree that it might be offensive for other people and they might have very personal reasons why they consider it offensive. So, you can't expect a generally accepted answer on your question.

Comment: @honk Really, they only asked why the editor found it offensive. Which would be found out by KugBuBu pinging and asking the editor directly. So they _could_ get an accepted answer in that case.

Comment: @Kendra: I completely agree with you. But the OP of this question asked _us_ why the editor found his phrase offensive. My opinion on this is that every person might have a personal view on that. This view might match the view of the editor or not. In any case, there is no generally accepted answer on this question. Even if the editor might explain why he found the phrase offensive, the OP of this question might still not accept the reason. Therefore I think this question is rather pointless.